# problem after installation of ubuntu on virtual machine

Tags: system-installation

upon restarting the virtual box after installation process of Ubuntu it ask for try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu. this process i have already done but it never restart each time it is the same problem.

im using window 10 ,oracle VM virtualBox and Ubuntu 18.04

can you help me please ?

Comment: it sounds like you are booting from the install media and not the hard disk you installed to

Comment: Try removing ISO image path from Storage in guest OS settings.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have left your installation media still attached to the guest machine. Remove it using the gif image below as a guide:

[image]